# Workaround 16MB BSON limit to delete multiple documents

Tags: mongodb, bson

I have my MongoDB data like that
[image]

Please look at the last field - time, as you can see, I have some "duplicate" data which have been marked with color.

For the small database, I can remove the duplicate values with below code

```
var cursor = db.getCollection("light").aggregate([
  {$group : {
    "_id": {
      index: "$index",
      unit: "$unit",
      min: "$min",
      max: "$max",
      node: "$node",
      year: { "$year": "$time" },
      dayOfYear: { "$dayOfYear": "$time" },
      hour: { "$hour": "$time" },
      minute: { "$minute": "$time" }
    },
    _id_not_delete: { $last: "$_id" }
}}
],
{ 
    "allowDiskUse" : true
}
)

var ids_not_delete = cursor.map(function (doc) { return doc._id_not_delete; });

db.getCollection("light").remove({"_id": { "$nin": ids_not_delete }});
```

But my database has more than 20 millions record, thus I receive this error

```
E QUERY    [js] Error: Converting from JavaScript to BSON failed: Object size 23146644 exceeds limit of 16793600 bytes. :
Bulk/addToOperationsList@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:611:28
Bulk/findOperations.remove@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:743:24
DBCollection.prototype.remove@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:404:13
@(shell):1:1
```

I know that the root cause is

```
The maximum BSON document size is 16 megabytes
```

I think I should change below code, but I don't have any good solution.

```
var ids_not_delete = cursor.map(function (doc) { return doc._id_not_delete; });
```

Do you have any ideas to optimize my code?

Example documents in the collection:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be22d5808c08300545effee"), 
    "index" : "LIGHT", 
    "unit" : "LUX", 
    "min" : NumberInt(5), 
    "max" : NumberInt(6), 
    "avg" : 5.5, 
    "node" : "TH", 
    "time" : ISODate("2018-11-07T00:10:00.091+0000")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be22b0052122e0047c3467c"), 
    "index" : "LIGHT", 
    "unit" : "LUX", 
    "min" : NumberInt(3), 
    "max" : NumberInt(5), 
    "avg" : NumberInt(4), 
    "node" : "TH", 
    "time" : ISODate("2018-11-07T00:00:00.204+0000")
},
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5be22b0008c08300545eff79"), 
    "index" : "LIGHT", 
    "unit" : "LUX", 
    "min" : NumberInt(3), 
    "max" : NumberInt(5), 
    "avg" : NumberInt(4), 
    "node" : "TH", 
    "time" : ISODate("2018-11-07T00:00:00.081+0000")
}
```

MongoDB shell version v4.0.2

MongoDB 4.0.0

Comment: What is the Mongodb Version ?

Comment: Delete by batches. If you add few documents to the question I could give a proper answer.

Comment: @AlexBlex I added sample documents

Comment: @rishabhagarwal MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
MongoDB 4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invert your aggregation to select ids you want to delete, rather than ones you want to keep:

```
const toDelete = db.getCollection("light").aggregate([
  { $group : {
    "_id": {
      index: "$index",
      unit: "$unit",
      min: "$min",
      max: "$max",
      node: "$node",
      year: { "$year": "$time" },
      dayOfYear: { "$dayOfYear": "$time" },
      hour: { "$hour": "$time" },
      minute: { "$minute": "$time" }
    },
    ids: {$push: "$_id"}
  } },
  {$project: {_id: {$slice: ["$ids", 1, 10000]}}},
  {$unwind: "$_id"},
  {$project: {_id: 0, deleteOne: { "filter" : { "_id" : "$_id"} } } }
]).toArray()
```

10,000 here is any big enough number significantly greater than expected number of duplicates within a group.

Then you can use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#execution-of-operations):

```
db.getCollection("light").bulkWrite(toDelete);
```

The driver will split the array by batches 100,000 deletions each.